# Magento2 price issues after data migration

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I have started the task of migrating to Magento2 from Magento 1.9.2.2;
So far everything has been successful except for a couple of issues.

My Environment is: Litespeed Enterprise 5.08, PHP 5.6.15, MYSQL 5.6

My Issue

1: The price field doesn't show when editing a configurable product, I have got "Use price of simple products" set to NO. I can see the price in the simple product if i edit that seperately.

2: The price in the category part of the catalogue shows the price EX tax, despite all settings being to show tax inclusive price. When i go to the category page, then choose both attribute options the price then changes to the tax inclusive price. At all times it is showing "WAS AU$XXX" on both category and product pages.

Answer (score 0):

For 1: Magento 2 do not supporting the managing of simple product's price on configurable product's level, instead used price of simple products.

For 2: hard to say anything, because resulting pricing depends on many configuration settings, advanced price settings, tax rules, catalog price rules, etc

Comment: for point 1, is the different to how standard Magento1 handles it? I don't recall doing a customisation to get that functionality.

Comment: Yes, it's different